# Full screen responsive grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, media-queries

I am trying to figure out how to build a full screen responsive grid but can't find anything definitive

Let me illustrate what I am trying to achieve.
On a full desktop screen, the grid must have 6 columns with a endless amount of repeating rows say each with a height of 300px. Inside each grid location will be an image

As the screen size reduces up until a tablet resolution, the 6 images per row will reduce in size to fit in. Once it reaches tablet resolution, it breaks so that there are only 4 columns now and hence 4 images per row.

It then repeats the same process until it comes to mobile size where it breaks to only 2 images per row. It doesn't have to be exactly that but something around the lines of that would be acceptable.

I have had a look at bootstrap and foundation but it seems the main container provided limits the max width preventing it from achieving a full screen layout.

What do you guys suggest? Hopefully you understand what I am getting at

Comment: i would suggest you to use bootstrap and wrap the row for header in a container that fits the window size.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have to be contained in width. You either use `.container` or `.container-fluid`.

Comment: yes Osama Ywar Khawaja is right. You should use bootstrap (getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite Bootstrap's container limits by using CSS.

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer, and you don't need to override the container limit with CSS, you can just use `.container-fluid`, Bootstraps full width container class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/grid.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then if you like to customize, try setting media queries.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Use this for image

```
<img src="sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Sample image">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The images in my box do not resize. My images are 320x280. The image stays at the size not re-sizing at all even when the columns get smaller and break. Why is this?

Comment: `<img src="sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Sample image">`